# Display results from query in a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, button, webforms

I have a .aspx page with a textbox, a button and a Listview control.

The user should write any text on the textbox, click the button and receive the results on the listview.

The method with the query:

```
public IQueryable<Midia> GetMidias(string busca)
    {
        var db = new Locadora.Models.LocadoraContexto();
        IQueryable<Midia> query = from m in db.Midias
                                      join f in db.Filmes on m.FilmeID equals f.FilmeID
                                      where f.TituloFilme.Contains(busca)
                                      select m;
        return query;
    }
```

The button click event:

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GetMidias(SearchTextBox.Text);
}
```

When the user clicks the button, the listview remains empty. The query is ok, I've already tested it on SQL Server Management Studio, and if I put it on the Page_Load event, the listview shows the data correctly. I don't know how to make it on the button_click.

The select method of the listview is: SelectMethod="GetMidias"

Comment: Why is GetMidias not void?

Comment: Looks like you have problem with databinding. A little more of the code where you do binding will help.

Comment: You're not show where you are updating the ListView or updating it.

Comment: What do you expect? You never set anything in the `ListView`.